# Can't match two SIFT descriptors with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection

I'm trying to match two `SIFT` descriptors with the simplest code I could've think of but the `OpenCV 3` keeps throwing exceptions.

This is my code:

```
cv::Mat img1 = imread(...); // Shortened for the example
cv::Mat img2 = imread(...); // Shortened for the example

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
Ptr<SIFT> ptrSift = SIFT::create(200, 3, 0.07, 15);
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
ptrSift->detectAndCompute(img1, Mat(), keypoints1, descriptors1, false);
ptrSift->detectAndCompute(img2, Mat(), keypoints2, descriptors2, false);
```

The code above brings me good results which I can visualize with the `drawKeypoints` function.

Then I use the following code to match the descriptors:

```
BFMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

But it keeps throwing:

> C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\features2d\src\matchers.cpp:722:
>   error: (-215) _queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescType in function
>   cv::BFMatcher::knnMatchImpl
>
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == src2.type() && src1.cols ==
>   src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)) in cv::batchDistance,
>   file C:\buil
>   ds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\stat.cpp,
>   line 3608 Exception:
>   C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\stat.cpp:3608:
>   error: (-215) type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2. cols && (type
>   == CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function cv::batchDistance

Thanks

Comment: I suggest use: http://robwhess.github.io/opensift/. It's very fast and easy to use.

Comment: You should check is descriptors1 or descriptors2 empty before match() call.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but they're not empty

Comment: Are there descriptors respectively rows in your descriptor matrices, which are zero vectors? I had this case once. Try a [FlannBasedMatcher](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html), as far as i know it can handle this case.

Comment: Look closely at the error.  Check if both images: (1) Are of type `CV_32F` or `CV_8U`, (2) they **both** are the same type, (3) if both columns of each image are the same.

Comment: @rayryeng even `matcher.match(descriptors, descriptors, matches);` fails...
@gfkri Tried with both `Flann` and `Brute`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite interesting, the code snippet below works for me fine:

```
cv::BFMatcher matcher;
std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;

cv::Mat descriptors1 = cv::Mat::eye(10, 10, CV_32F);
cv::Mat descriptors2 = cv::Mat::eye(10, 10, CV_32F);
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

Can you check it? Could you provide the size and type of your descriptors? Finally, have you tried both in release/debug mode?

p.s.: wich version do you use? You should try to overwrite and recompile matchers.cpp with the latest version: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commits/master/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp

Comment: Well this seems to work. I guess the matrix wasn't `CV_32F` like someone suggested before in the comments to the original question. Now I have a problem with my `SiftDescriptorExtractor`... Saying the code isn't implemented... Thanks anyway